Show $\Delta x\Vert D_x^c u\Vert\leq\Vert u\Vert$
Let $\Delta x>0, N>0$ and $I=\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$. For $u=(u_i)_{i\in I}$, one defines
$$
(D_x^c u)_i=\frac{u_{i+1}-u_{i-1}}{2\Delta x}\textrm{ for all }i\in I\tag{Def}
$$
and for $u_k=(u_{k,i})_{i\in I}$ with $k=1,2$ one defines
$$
\langle u_1,u_2\rangle=\sum_{i\in I}\Delta x u_{1,i}u_{2,i}.
$$
Moreover, let $\lVert\cdot\Vert$ denote the corresponding norm.
It is said that, for all $u=(u_i)_{i\in I}$, by definition (Def) and the periodic boundary conditions, one has
$$
\Delta x\Vert D_x^c u\Vert\leq\Vert u\Vert.
$$
How to see that?

Using
$$
\sum_{i\in I}\Delta x u_{i\pm 1}^2=\sum_{i\in I}\Delta x u_i^2
$$
due to the periodic boundary conditions, I first get
$$
\begin{align*}
(\Delta x)^2\Vert D_x^c u\Vert^2&=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{i\in I}\Delta x (u_{i+1}-u_{i-1})^2\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\Vert u\Vert^2-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i\in I}\Delta x u_{i+1}u_{i-1}
\end{align*}
$$
By Cauchy-Schwarz, I then get
$$
\left(\sum_{i\in I}\Delta x u_{i+1} u_{i-1}\right)^2\leq\left(\sum_{i\in I}\Delta x u_{i+1}^2\right)\left(\sum_{i\in I}\Delta x u_{i-1}^2\right)=\Vert u\Vert^2
$$
Both together should imply the statement.
Would be great to get some feedback whether I am right.
